# .net REST API - MQTT client, not working simultaneously

Tags: c#, .net, mqtt

bellow API is called when ever i need to pass a message to the broker.
when i call this API simultaneously (from an app phone, 2 different phones with 2 different userIds) , only one record is saved in the database(but both records arrivs to the broker),
These are 2 different transactions, and when ever it connect to the broker its with a different
client Id (client id is the user id).
any ideas why this is happening?

```
public IHttpActionResult UnlockCart(string mac, string userId, string gMac)
{
    // Acquire the access token.

    var factory = new MqttFactory();
    string topicC = "sOc/" + gMac + "/c";
    string topicS = "sOc/" + gMac + "/s";
    _client = factory.CreateMqttClient();
    _client.UseConnectedHandler(e =>
    {
        //Subscribe to topic
        _client.SubscribeAsync(new MqttTopicFilterBuilder().WithTopic(topicS).Build()).Wait();
    });
    _client.UseApplicationMessageReceivedHandler(async e =>
    {
        JObject json = JObject.Parse(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.ApplicationMessage.Payload));
        //
        // save record in DB
        //
       await  _client.DisconnectAsync();
    });
   
    _options = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
                .WithClientId(userId)
                .WithTcpServer("XX.XXX.XX.XXX", 1883).WithCredentials("myBroker", "mypass")
                .WithCleanSession()
                .Build();
    //connect
    _client.ConnectAsync(_options).Wait();

    DateTime currentDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now,
         TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Israel Standard Time"));
    long unixTime = ((DateTimeOffset)currentDate).ToUnixTimeSeconds();
    string payload = "{\"s\":1,\"m\":\"" + mac + "\",\"i\":12345}";
    var pubMsg = new MqttApplicationMessageBuilder().WithTopic(topicC).WithPayload(payload).
    WithAtMostOnceQoS().Build();
    if (_client.IsConnected)
    {
        var result = _client.PublishAsync(pubMsg);
    }
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: If you see both messages arriving at the broker, what makes you think the problem is with the publishing client and to with the subscribing client that is doing the database update?

Comment: this code is publishing the message to the broker,
when called one transaction by one then it works fine, im thinking its something with the connection to the client, but it has to be here